# Force GCC to forgo zeroing certain globals

Tags: c, gcc

Is there any way to tell GCC to not initialize a particular global array to zero?

I want to reserve a large chunk of memory for storing a large data structure that my code manages, so I say:

```
#define SIZE_16_MB 0x01000000
BYTE mChunkSpace[SIZE_16_MB];
```

The problem is that crtinit() takes a million years to initialize this space to zero, and it is not at all necessary.

Is there any way I can force it not to initialize that space?

Currently I am hard-coding a memory address that is outside what the linker knows about, but that is not a particularly robust way of doing things.

Additionally, this is a slow embedded proc (50MHz Microblaze), so don't assume that i am talking about a PC.  It really does take a long time to zero that space.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `gcc` attributes to store the object in another new memory section, like for example in the `.noinit` memory section.

```
 BYTE mChunkSpace[SIZE_16_MB] __attribute__ ((section (".noinit")));
```

Comment: I stumbled across this myself, but I had a hard time figuring out exactly how it is implemented and if it would be available to the OP on his target platform.  From what I can tell a `.noinit` section is created in the `.bss` section.  Does this mean it is not zero initialized *and* does not take up ~16MB of space in the executable?

Comment: @EdS. `size -A -x` shows me the addresses of the memory section is different than the addresses of the `.bss`section.

Comment: I am repeating what I read here: http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/mem_sections.html

Comment: ...though now I notice this is avr-libc specific, not sure if it applies here.

Comment: @EdS. crt0 can still zeroize any new memory section by default on x86, this need to be checked I think.

Answer (score 4):

Try dynamic initialization:

```
BYTE* mChunkSpace = (BYTE*)malloc(SIZE_16_MB * sizeof(BYTE));
```

Then this data is uninitialized and waiting for you to initialize it.

Comment: That is a good solution, but it would mean making my heap segment much larger.  That might be OK if it doesn't impact the performance of the heap in other contexts.

Answer (score 2):

Most answers you’ll get here on SO will be slanted toward either Visual Studio or GCC, both on general purpose platforms (i.e. PC’s, whether Windows or Linux), and will be heavy on the “the standard says...” citations, none of which apply all that much for small embedded systems, unless you happen to be running embedded Linux or Windows CE.

ouah’s answer is probably the closest to what you need... perhaps EXACTLY what you need, if you're truly using GCC.  Since the memory chunk you want is so large, probably consuming the lion’s share of your system’s memory, your best bet is to define a special section in your build’s linker command file, or by linker directives in either a C, C++, or assembly file.  The syntax for doing so will vary by compiler.  If you use linker directives in a source/assembly file, there are probably attributes you'll need to specify regarding the memory region's read/write-ability, etc... or perhaps not, if the Microblaze has no MMU/Memory-controller.  You’ll need to put a linker symbol at the start of the section, and in your C code, use an “extern char symName[]” directive so your C code can compile in relocs that the linker will overwrite with the actual address of the section.  Depending on the compiler and architecture, you may also need to declare the symName[] extern with some sort of “far” attribute; I don’t know enough about the Microblaze to say anything about that.

Answer (score -1):

The standard states that static data which is not explicitly initialized at the point of declaration will be zero-initialized.  You can avoid runtime initialization by initializing the first element to a non-zero value yourself:

```
#define SIZE_16_MB 0x01000000
BYTE mChunkSpace[SIZE_16_MB] = {1};
```

Note that, if you specify `0`, the compiler will likely just store it in the `.bss` section anyway, i.e., it will still be initialized at runtime.  It doesn't have to do this, but it would be stupid not to.  So now your array gets thrown into the `.data` segment.

Of course, this will make the resultant executable much larger (~16MB larger to be exact), but the memory will not be initialized at runtime.  So the question comes down to what maters to you; the time needed to zero that memory, or the resultant executable size?

Comment: Sorry for this non-constructive comment—I don't have a good solution, I almost suggested making `mChunkSpace` a local of `main()`, as a joke, but it is unlikely to work in practice. Anyway, when you say “but the memory will not be initialized at runtime”: it will be loaded from permanent storage instead. This is unlikely to be faster.

Comment: You can control whether gcc puts zero-initialized variables into .bss with the -f[no-]zero-initialized-in-bss flag. The default is -fzero-initialized-in-bss

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Hardly non-constructive!  I think it is very constructive as I had not considered that at all.

Comment: @PascalCuoq On a paged system, the mChunkSpace will be read from disk as needed, so startup time will be less. Although, on such systems, crtinit should not be clearing pages that are allocated and zeroed by the OS on demand.

Comment: This answer is *completely* wrong: `BYTE mChinkSpace[16_MB] = {1};` asks the compiler to initialize the element `0` to `1`, and to default-initialize *all* other elements to `0`. This is strictly worse than the original.

Comment: @EmployedRussian: I said exactly that.  The *compiler* performs the intialization.  Why is it "strictly worse" exactly? (not saying you're wrong, but I'd like an explanation for my own understanding as I've never encountered this problem myself).  Perhaps it doesn't solve the OP's problem, but it's not wrong in the sense that the data itself will no longer be initialized after the program begins.

Comment: @EmployedRussian: Eh?  I really would like to hear your explanation. As many others do, I answer questions around here to learn new things, so if I'm wrong I'd like to learn why.

Comment: A large executable is very undesirable in this application -- it makes field-updating the flash ROM much more cumbersome.

Comment: @NXT: That much I figured (and noted in my response).  If that's the problem then at least I understand why this won't help you.  I looked into ouah's method as well, but didn't feel I understood it well enough to propose it as an answer.  Hope that gets you were you need to be.

Comment: @EdS. I think I misunderstood what you meant. You said "but the memory will not be initialized at runtime" which can reasonably be interpreted as "the values will remain uninitialized at runtime". What you really meant appears to be: the `.data` will be loaded from on-disk image (which will now contain a bunch of zeros), but at least there will not be a loop to zero-initialize the array (it will likely be replaced with a bunch of `read()`s instead). If that's indeed what you meant, then the answer is not wrong, merely somewhat unclear.