# C, skip initialisation static array

Tags: c, gcc

Is there a way to instruct gcc to skip initialization for certain static,volatile variables?
I have several circular buffers (declared volatile) that really don't need to be zeroed at startup and on my MCU, it's a waste of about ~2500 tcy.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: conditional compilation using `#ifdef..... #endif` ??

Comment: hmm... I'm speaking about runtime here, not design time.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180892/force-gcc-to-forgo-zeroing-certain-globals

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use `gcc`, you can place the array object in the `.noinit` section:

```
uint8_t arr[1024] __attribute__ ((section (".noinit")));
```

Comment: Doesn't this extension contradict the C standard?

Comment: @icepack - probably yes - that's why it's an extension.

Comment: Do you happen to know a similar one for MSVC?

Comment: @user93353 well, another possibility is that it's not a contradiction but an innovation that will be adopted sometime, like the changes in C++11 that follow boost in many ways

Comment: @icepack no, I don't know a way to achieve this with MSVC

Comment: @ouah thanks a lot sir, this is what I was looking for. Btw. I really don't care about C standard, my app is not a demo and should perform like I want to.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername: No, this does not contradict the C standard. The C standard  says that C implementations may have extensions, and that extensions that do not alter the behavior of *strictly conforming* programs (which do not use extensions) are *conforming*. GCC’s `__attribute__` keyword is a reserved identifier (because it starts with `__`), so no strictly conforming programs use it (by definition, any program that uses it is not strictly conforming), so accepting it is a conforming extension.

Comment: @EricPostpischil How about this scenario: a user declares `extern uint8_t arr[1024];` in one module and depends on the implementation of this array in another module (and for example, expects it to be zero-initialized). Won't this be considered a change of the conforming program? Btw, this thread is about 10 years old...

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername: The program is the whole program. If any one part of the program uses this GCC `__attribute__` extension, it is not a conforming program. The rule in the C standard is not that the behavior of code in one translation unit that is, by itself, strictly conforming, will not be affected. The rule for what is a conforming extension is that if any program is entirely strictly conforming, then the extension will not change its behavior.

Comment: @EricPostpischil A program might conform in version 1 but might become non-conforming in version 2. Is program conformity term well-defined?