# How not to initialise a static variable with GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, static-initialization

I am programming a micro in C++. I need a static variable to survive across a reset.

The object is used to hold more detailed information about the reason for the reset. I can't be guaranteed that I can log it to flash at time of reset, so I need to log it after the reset.

I can use pointer constants and manually allocate a block of ram that is not given to the linker in the segments file.... and do in place initialisation.

But I was wondering is there a way of using attributes or something similar in gcc that will allow me to avoid static initialisation of a static variable. This makes it slightly more portable between the different micros I am using as I don't have to fiddle with the memory map manually.

I need the standard object constructors to work when the object is assigned explicitly.

Comment: You could make a new section that is stored in RAM but isn't part of `.data` or `.bss`, which would not be touched by the start-up code. What micro is it? Some of them have persistent scratchpad registers that survive a reset.

Comment: You might not even need a separate section if you can read the variable you want _before_ copying the `.data` section into RAM. I did that on a recent STM32 project, it woks fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C, skip initialisation static array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17760755/c-skip-initialisation-static-array)

Comment: I have actually a few: STM, GD, ESP .... which is why I was trying to avoid playing with the memory map manually. Also the block is about 80 bytes as it includes stack trace of the function calls before the failure, so it doesn't fit into the scratch pad registers.

Comment: @nielsen Given this line from [GCC's documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Variable-Attributes.html): "This attribute is specific to ELF targets and relies on the linker script to place sections with the .noinit prefix in the right location.", I don't think the linked question is a full duplicate of this one.  Not requiring initialization is not the same as retaining value when restarted.  Not initializing is a prerequisite, but it's not by itself sufficient.

Comment: And it's certainly not a dupe given the attribute immediately after `noinit` [on that same page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Variable-Attributes.html): `persistent`.  "Any data with the persistent attribute will not be initialized by the C runtime startup code, but will be initialized by the program loader. This enables the value of the variable to ‘persist’ between processor resets."

Comment: There seem to be some additional issues raised by C++ code and GCC that make the "no init" only part of the solution. The code I am using is C++ and there seems to be problem with the generated code if the initialisation of the class variables are done inline with the declaration and no init attribute raised on the class, calling the constructor explicitly to initialise the class fails with garbage. If the initialisation is moved to the constructor initialisation list they are constructed correctly.